# PV solar panel inverter

Tags: inverter

I am designing an inverter for a project. The main focus of the project is to design a standalone inverter that is able to produce variable voltage output.
A secondary aim is to have the system solar powered.

I want to understand how to vary the output voltage of the inverter to match the voltage requirements of the connected load. Some AC loads have different voltage ratings.  e.g in South Africa, voltage rating of AC loads may be 220Vrms, 230Vrms or 240Vrms. I realise that it will usually be possible to set the inverter output to a compromise voltage but in this case, designing a variable output voltage inverter is a specific aim.

So, the main question is, how will I vary the output voltage from the inverter to match the load connected.

Comment: @PeterJ, Peter Smith, Asmyldof, uint128_t, Daniel Grillo: The intention of the original question was completely clear to me qand seemed well focused. It would be useful to know why you thought otherwise. Question edited. Please vote to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have enough energy available to supply the load at the chosen voltage then you do it the same way as for any regulated power supply.

The most common method is to sample the output voltage, divide it down to a more convenient lower voltage and use a comparator or functional equivalent to compare it to a reference.

In the case of AC you COULD create an AC reference but this is harder than is needed. Instead, rectify the divided output signal and compare it to a reference DC signal and then provide a higher step up voltage if output is too low and the provide a lower step up voltage if output is too high.

Your question may not be exactly what is intended. If the above does not answer it please be more specific.

Comment: The idea is that the standalone inverter can be connected to any AC load found in the household with manual selection of the required voltage rating. Therefore, the challenges of this project include design of a solar power system and a  standalone inverter that is able to produce variable voltage output (main focus of the project).

Comment: @jabu In most cases using eg 230 VAC with appliances rated at 220 or 230 or 240 v makes minimal difference, BUT if it's an aim of the project that's fine. | So my above answer applies. Divide output down to say a few volts. Use a "precision rectifier" to produce proportional DC and compare to a DC reference to control power converter. This is a standard approach.

Comment: thanks for your help, at least you gave me the direction to follow, I will have to research more regarding that for the project.

Answer (score 0):

I would design the inverter to produce the same voltage as your normal commercial power supply, as I would expect all the appliances are intended to be used with that voltage. (You probably don't have separate 220 V, 230 V, and 240 V outlets that you use depending in the rated voltage of the appliance.)

Comment: Thanks peter, but the main aim of the project was to have a variable output Voltage even though a fixed would not affect the appliances.

Answer (score 0):

I would design a DC/AC power electronic converter with pulse width modulation, the easiest circuit would be a half bridge converter. By accurately controlling the duty cycle of the PWM signal you will be able to control the AC voltage.